# ios prefs url path scheme to mail

Tags: ios, email, url, schema

I can't seem to find anywhere the path to Seetings-> Mail,Contacts,Calendars url scheme path.

I've tried : `@"prefs:root=Mail,Contacts,Calendars"` but it's only opening Settings and center the table to Mail,Contacts,Calendars.

Any idea how to go into that?

Thanks

Comment: Anyway custom URL scheme support is dropped on iOS 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Try this url : `[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS"]`

You can also try : `[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS&path=ADD_ACCOUNT"];`
Directly for Add Account page in setting.

Let me know if you have any issue.