# How do I open phone settings when a button is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, settings

I am trying to implement a feature in an App that shows an alert when the internet connection is not available.
The alert has two actions (OK and Settings), whenever a user clicks on settings, I want to take them to the phone settings programmatically.

I am using Swift and Xcode.

Answer (score 405, accepted):

Using `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString`

Update for Swift 5.1

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController (title: "Title", message: "Go to Settings?", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in

        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
            })
        }
    }
    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Swift 4.2

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController (title: "Title", message: "Go to Settings?", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in

        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
            })
        }
    }
    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: How do i implement that ? @Marius Fanu

Comment: it using iOS8 @Marius Fanu

Comment: @AyoolaSolomon I've updated my answer to add an alert on `viewDidAppear` method, with the `Settings` and `Cancel` button

Comment: Is there a way i can navigate back to the app programmatically

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. In order to go to your app, your application should implement a custom URL scheme, and call the `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(yourCustomURL)` from the current app, but you don't have that access from the Settings app

Comment: @MariusFanu This solution is not working for iOS 10 . I am working on Xcode 8, swift 3. Any alternate solution please?

Comment: @PersianBlue is correct in iOS 10.1.1 this fails to launch the Settings app.

Comment: You may want to update the settingsURL string to UIApplication.openSettingsURLString

Comment: Is this apple allowed when we use `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString`, because apple rejected when we open the settings app some times.

Comment: This opens the app specific page in the settings application, any idea how to open settings on the main page?

Answer (score 295):

> ⚠️ Be careful!
>
> This answer is based on undocumented APIs and recently (since iOS12) Apple is rejecting apps with this approach.

*Original answer below*

**Swift 5**

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

**Swift 4**

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

**NOTE: The following method works for all the versions below iOS 11, for higher versions the app might get rejected since it's a private API**

Sometimes we want to take a user to settings other than our app settings.
The following method will help you achieve that:

First, configure the URL Schemes in your project. You will find it in Target -> Info -> URL Scheme. click on + button and type prefs in URL Schemes

[image]

**Swift 5**

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "App-prefs:Bluetooth")!)
```

**Swift 3**

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=General")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

**Swift**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=General")!)
```

**Objective-C**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];
```

and following are all the available URLs

**On IOS < 12 **

- prefs:root=General&path=About
- prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
- prefs:root=AIRPLANE_MODE
- prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK
- prefs:root=General&path=USAGE/CELLULAR_USAGE
- prefs:root=Brightness
- prefs:root=Bluetooth
- prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
- prefs:root=FACETIME
- prefs:root=General
- prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
- prefs:root=CASTLE
- prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
- prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
- prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES
- prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
- prefs:root=MUSIC
- prefs:root=MUSIC&path=EQ
- prefs:root=MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit
- prefs:root=General&path=Network
- prefs:root=NIKE_PLUS_IPOD
- prefs:root=NOTES
- prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
- prefs:root=Phone
- prefs:root=Photos
- prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
- prefs:root=General&path=Reset
- prefs:root=Sounds&path=Ringtone
- prefs:root=Safari
- prefs:root=General&path=Assistant
- prefs:root=Sounds
- prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
- prefs:root=STORE
- prefs:root=TWITTER
- prefs:root=FACEBOOK
- prefs:root=General&path=USAGE prefs:root=VIDEO
- prefs:root=General&path=Network/VPN
- prefs:root=Wallpaper
- prefs:root=WIFI
- prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING
- prefs:root=Phone&path=Blocked
- prefs:root=DO_NOT_DISTURB

**On IOS 13**

- App-prefs:General&path=About
- App-prefs:AIRPLANE_MODE
- App-prefs:General&path=AUTOLOCK
- App-prefs:Bluetooth
- App-prefs:General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
- App-prefs:FACETIME
- App-prefs:General
- App-prefs:General&path=Keyboard
- App-prefs:CASTLE
- App-prefs:CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
- App-prefs:General&path=INTERNATIONAL
- App-prefs:MUSIC
- App-prefs:NOTES
- App-prefs:NOTIFICATIONS_ID
- App-prefs:Phone
- App-prefs:Photos
- App-prefs:General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
- App-prefs:General&path=Reset
- App-prefs:Sounds&path=Ringtone
- App-prefs:Sounds
- App-prefs:General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
- App-prefs:STORE
- App-prefs:Wallpaper
- App-prefs:WIFI
- App-prefs:INTERNET_TETHERING
- App-prefs:DO_NOT_DISTURB

**Not tested**

- App-prefs:TWITTER (??)
- App-prefs:FACEBOOK (??)
- App-prefs:NIKE_PLUS_IPOD (??)

✅ **Tested** IOS > 12

- App-prefs:HEALTH&path=SOURCES

**Note:** Network setting will not be opened in a simulator, but the link will work on a real device.

Comment: And just opening the settings without a specific page: "prefs:root"

Comment: Interesting, I just tested it on ios 7 & 9. It works!

Comment: Url schema for Bluetooth settings is now "prefs:root=Bluetooth"

Comment: We were just rejected for using a private api.

Comment: @jestro, did Apple rejected your app even after adding "prefs" in Xcode's URL Schemas? Because i see lot of apps in app store, which takes player to any settings screen.

Comment: Anyone knows the url for the blocked callers? (settings -> Phone -> Calls -> Blocked) and for do not disturb mode (settings -> Do Not Disturb) ?

Comment: How about opening Mail settings? it seems there's no url option for mail settings.

Comment: Sorry @Hokage there is not URL available to open Mail settings.

Comment: @Karl-JohnChow You can use  "prefs:root=Phone&path=Blocked" for blocked calls
and "prefs:root=DO_NOT_DISTURB" for Do Not Disturb

Comment: @vivektakrani actually there is: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404107/ios-prefs-url-path-scheme-to-mail

Comment: Yeah just checked and it's working...and btw it's already there in the list above :D

Comment: This doesn't work with iOS 10. Ran the same code on iOS 9.3. and it worked, ran on iOS 10 and it didn't (regardless of which url is used)

Comment: Any solution for iOS 10?

Comment: prefs:root=FACEBOOK not working in iOS 10.1 and Xcode 8.1 but working fine in iOS 9.3.5   does any have solution?

Comment: Worked well for me - iOS10, Note:- Don't change **prefs** with anything else.

Comment: prefs:root=FACEBOOK but not works could assist me here? @ZaidPathan

Comment: @SaumilShah Have you added **prefs** In URL schemes?

Comment: Yes I used " UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "prefs:root=FACEBOOK")!)" code and also added Xcode Target -> Info -> URL Types -> URL Schemes  "prefs" strings.

Comment: How did you find out the path names @vivektakrani?

Comment: How to just go to the root of the settings?

Comment: @prettyitgirl.com try this UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"prefs:root")!)

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that as soon as I posted my comment. :) Also, Apps-Pref works on iOS 10.

Comment: For iOS 10, use `App-Prefs` instead of `prefs` as the scheme of the URL string. e.g. `App-Prefs:root=WIFI`

Comment: App-Prefs works for iOS 10, but is it legal. Apple might reject the application as it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: For me it only works inside the simulator.. not on device. Trying to open the Safari Prefs

Comment: Is it possible to open settings for custom app, like: prefs:root=myApp ?

Comment: IS POSSIBLE TO ACCESS: Storage & iCloud Usage -> Manage Storage

Comment: Also use UPPER CASE if this keys don't work. For example `WALLPAPER` instead of `Wallpaper`.

Comment: @barola_mes Yes you can by replacing this **"App-Prefs:root=General"** with **UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString**

Comment: In ios11 it Opens Setting default page.

Comment: recently gave an app into review to release it in the App Store, and Apple declined it because of the usage of "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root". I used it to open the wifi settings, when the user has no internet connection.

Comment: Since iOS 12 coming out soon, Apple rejecting app which include such pref. Please be-aware of it. Even my app got rejected too

Comment: DO NOT use `App-Prefs` or `prefs:root` as these are private API's, and unless you are very lucky your app will get rejected.

Comment: my app was rejected for an update by apple for using prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES

Comment: Yes ..exactly these are the private apis and app will get reject by apple.

Comment: So what is everyone doing to fix this the right way?

Comment: Be careful it is a private API, you'll be rejected at Apple Store submission

Comment: What is the alternative for iOS 12?

Comment: @ThihaAung so any better solution?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0, now all `App-Prefs` and `pref` are non-public url now. The best way to handle was, show the popup, inside show navigation steps [GIF or Images Slides] then when user click "ok", leads to setting using this `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString `

Comment: Since Facebook SDK used URL Types I can't open Settings page. The code that you gave opens only Settings>My Application Name. Is there a way to fix it.

Comment: hi, is possibile to open iphone storage page?

Comment: for open storage page?

Comment: "App-prefs:MESSAGES" works for me to open Messages Setting from App.

Answer (score 73):

**SWIFT 5**

```
if let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {

   UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl)

 }
```

In iOS 8+ you can do the following:

```
 func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))
    }
```

**Swift 4**

```
    let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
    UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl)
```

Comment: This takes you to the app specific settings, how do I take them to the general settings page or even better to the health section?

Comment: Swift 3 - `UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)`

Comment: @AceGreen did you make it to the health section?

Comment: How do you open just the Settings app? The "Home page" of it

Comment: without "!" sign ```URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString).map { UIApplication.shared.open($0, options: [:], completionHandler: nil) }```

Comment: Is this apple allowed when we use UIApplication.openSettingsURLString, because apple rejected when we open the settings app some times.

Answer (score 24):

Using @vivek's hint I develop an utils class based on **Swift 3**, hope you appreciate!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public enum PreferenceType: String {

    case about = "General&path=About"
    case accessibility = "General&path=ACCESSIBILITY"
    case airplaneMode = "AIRPLANE_MODE"
    case autolock = "General&path=AUTOLOCK"
    case cellularUsage = "General&path=USAGE/CELLULAR_USAGE"
    case brightness = "Brightness"
    case bluetooth = "Bluetooth"
    case dateAndTime = "General&path=DATE_AND_TIME"
    case facetime = "FACETIME"
    case general = "General"
    case keyboard = "General&path=Keyboard"
    case castle = "CASTLE"
    case storageAndBackup = "CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP"
    case international = "General&path=INTERNATIONAL"
    case locationServices = "LOCATION_SERVICES"
    case accountSettings = "ACCOUNT_SETTINGS"
    case music = "MUSIC"
    case equalizer = "MUSIC&path=EQ"
    case volumeLimit = "MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit"
    case network = "General&path=Network"
    case nikePlusIPod = "NIKE_PLUS_IPOD"
    case notes = "NOTES"
    case notificationsId = "NOTIFICATIONS_ID"
    case phone = "Phone"
    case photos = "Photos"
    case managedConfigurationList = "General&path=ManagedConfigurationList"
    case reset = "General&path=Reset"
    case ringtone = "Sounds&path=Ringtone"
    case safari = "Safari"
    case assistant = "General&path=Assistant"
    case sounds = "Sounds"
    case softwareUpdateLink = "General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK"
    case store = "STORE"
    case twitter = "TWITTER"
    case facebook = "FACEBOOK"
    case usage = "General&path=USAGE"
    case video = "VIDEO"
    case vpn = "General&path=Network/VPN"
    case wallpaper = "Wallpaper"
    case wifi = "WIFI"
    case tethering = "INTERNET_TETHERING"
    case blocked = "Phone&path=Blocked"
    case doNotDisturb = "DO_NOT_DISTURB"

}
```

---

```
enum PreferenceExplorerError: Error {
    case notFound(String)
}

open class PreferencesExplorer {

    // MARK: - Class properties -

    static private let preferencePath = "App-Prefs:root"

    // MARK: - Class methods -

    static func open(_ preferenceType: PreferenceType) throws {
        let appPath = "\(PreferencesExplorer.preferencePath)=\(preferenceType.rawValue)"
        if let url = URL(string: appPath) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
               UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        } else {
            throw PreferenceExplorerError.notFound(appPath)
        }
    }

}
```

This is very helpful since that API's will change for sure and you can refactor once and very fast!

Comment: Would this go through apple review?

Comment: I am going to add one more thing to make it slightly better. In the enum, you can make a variable of type String with the name urlString. Then return "App-Prefs:root=" = self.rawValue. This will basically remove the need for appPath and the static private let. Cheers.

Comment: Notification settings is not opening on iOS 11.

Comment: Any answer for notification settings on iOS 11?

Comment: this will not work as we got this message from app: "Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store."

Comment: @L_Sonic no it will not pass review, and if it does, it could get randomly flagged in any future updates you push

Answer (score 21):

The first response from [App-Specific URL Schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988241/url-scheme-open-settings-ios) worked for me on iOS 10.3.

```
if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString + Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appSettings) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings)
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's this supposed to open?

Answer (score 13):

`App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION` worked for me for getting to general location settings. Note: only works on a device.

Comment: This gets rejected

Answer (score 11):

**iOS 12+**

The `open(url:options:completionHandler:)` method has been updated to include a non-nil options dictionary, which as of this post only contains one possible option of type `UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey` (in the example).

```
@objc func openAppSpecificSettings() {
    guard let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {
            return
    }
    let optionsKeyDictionary = [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey(rawValue: "universalLinksOnly"): NSNumber(value: true)]
    
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: optionsKeyDictionary, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

**Explicitly constructing a URL, such as with "App-Prefs", has gotten some apps rejected from the store.**

Comment: I confirm this, app was fine with "App-Prefs" before, but after Apple's Special Event my update got rejection, falling back to UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString.

Comment: Is this apple allowed when we use UIApplication.openSettingsURLString, because apple rejected when we open the settings app some times.

Answer (score 8):

word of warning: the `prefs:root` or `App-Prefs:root` URL schemes are considered private API. Apple may reject you app if you use those, here is what you may get when submitting your app:

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change. Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality using the "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme.
>
> If there are no alternatives for providing the functionality your app requires, you can file an enhancement request.

Comment: There’s no supported way to open Settings to the Wi-Fi/Language/Location ‘page’.  The fact that this worked in iOS 9 is a bug that’s been fixed in iOS 10. For more info please refer https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/186656#186656

Answer (score 7):

in ios10/ Xcode 8 in simulator:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

works

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"prefs:root=General")!)
```

does not.

Comment: Has the `NS` prefix been removed in iOS 10?

Comment: This will only work if your app have .bundle file (your app preferences)

Comment: @Sophy Swicz HOw can I add .bundle file?

Comment: @Developer https://github.com/phynet/SettingBundleiOSProject  also, your app settings are all the services that your app allows to use and are shown in General -> settings of your app

Answer (score 7):

I have seen this line of code

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication() .openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=General")!)
```

is not working, it didn't work for me in ios10/ Xcode 8, just a small code difference, please replace this with

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"App-Prefs:root=General")!)
```

**Swift3**

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"prefs:root=General")!)
```

Replace with

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=General")!)
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: Causes: App rejected

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @Luca Davanzo

iOS 11, some permissions settings have moved to the app path:

> **iOS 11 Support**

```
 static func open(_ preferenceType: PreferenceType) throws {
    var preferencePath: String
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *), preferenceType == .video || preferenceType == .locationServices || preferenceType == .photos {
        preferencePath = UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString
    } else {
        preferencePath = "\(PreferencesExplorer.preferencePath)=\(preferenceType.rawValue)"
    }

    if let url = URL(string: preferencePath) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    } else {
        throw PreferenceExplorerError.notFound(preferencePath)
    }
}
```

Comment: can this go through Apple Review? I mean, will this lead to app rejection?

Comment: when I run this code, I just takes me to the settings page. Not the specific settings tab in it.

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 4**

This could take your app's specific settings, if that's what you're looking for.

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

Comment: thanks... I have that working... but I want to change settings on apps that are by other developers.  For example, press a button and change the Push notification settings of facebook so they do not message during a meeting.  I predict there could be an MDM solutions... or not.

Comment: @IrishGringo the only way to change the settings of the Facebook app is for the user to open the settings of the Facebook app themselves by navigating via the General Settings >> Notifications >> Facebook

Answer (score 3):

`UIApplication.open(_:options:completionHandler:)` must be used from main thread only

**Solution:**

```
if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString + Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!) {
  if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appSettings) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As above @niravdesai said App-prefs. 
I found that `App-Prefs:` works for both iOS 9, 10 and 11. devices tested. 
where as `prefs:` only works on iOS 9.