# How can I open bluetooth setting on button press in ios9?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I want to open bluetooth setting page on click of one button. Currently, it is opening General page.

I am doing following for that:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=Bluetooth"]];
```

Comment: from iOS9 you can opne setting app but i dont think you can open Bluetooth window directly. for open setting you can use `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`

Comment: please,Check This Answer ------>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34024467/475978

Answer (score 0):

Now you can open only current app settings, sorry ..... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html

You can on/off bluetooth by

```
BluetoothManager *manager = [BluetoothManager sharedInstance];
[manager setEnabled:![manager enabled]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL Scheme:

> prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth

Below is the code:

```
NSURL*url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
```

This will work for opening General screen in Settings for bluetooth

P.S.: Don't forget to add `URL Types` in targets info.plist file as shown below:

[image: URL Types]