# How to programmatically open the Bluetooth settings in iOS 11

Tags: swift3, bluetooth, settings, ios11, swift4

Code that I used for iOS 10 no longer works on iOS 11... Any ideas what to change? I need to open Bluetooth Settings not general iOS Settings that is getting opened by code below

```
if let settings = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(settings, options:[:], completionHandler:nil)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i open phone settings when a button is clicked ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152526/how-do-i-open-phone-settings-when-a-button-is-clicked-ios)

Comment: Nope. Code that is there is not working!!!. It will take you to settings page only

Comment: Having the same problem. Still no one has an answer?

Comment: I have heard Apple removed that feature but not 100% confident ....

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 11 onwards, Apple has suggested to use public APIs or remove the functionality using “prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme which is a private entity.

So if you use above url schemes your app might get reject. If you want to open app settings, use **UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString**.