# How to open general settings page (home page, not app settings)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I'd like to redirect the user to the general settings page, not the application settings page (with permissions, etc.). Is that possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=General")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: That will get your app rejected though.

Answer (score -1):

Try this!!

```
 let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
 if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as! URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as! URL)
 }
```

To navigate to specific page, check this link:
[How do i open phone settings when a button is clicked ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152526/how-do-i-open-phone-settings-when-a-button-is-clicked-ios)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I want the general settings page.

Comment: Check the link...That might help you to navigate to different pages!!