# How to create a button with repeated permission to turn on the camera in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm doing a project with a camera on SwiftUI, I added permissions to info.plist for the camera to work.
The problem is, if you do not give permission, then the camera will not work.
I want to add a button when you click on it, a request to turn on the camera appeared again.
Or how to call the request again until the user agrees to enable it?
I have looked through various articles and videos, I have not found any information, I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: I believe if the user revokes permission, at that point, they must be directed to the Settings app to change it later on — I don’t think the app can continue prompting for it.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically send it to the settings?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152662/4311935