# Is there any way to open a specific Settings page from my own iOS app?

Tags: swift, uikit, uiapplication

I want to open a specific device Settings page (e.g. Bluetooth) from my own iOS app.
As far as I know ([How do I open phone settings when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152526/how-do-i-open-phone-settings-when-a-button-is-clicked)), previously (in iOS 11 and below versions) it was possible to open a specific Settings page with
`UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "App-prefs:Bluetooth»!)`, but now it is highly likely that my application will be rejected because it is a private API.

My question: **is there any way to open a specific device Settings page**, or is all I am allowed to do is to open my application's settings page via

```
if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

There really is a lot of information on this subject, but I'm afraid it's already outdated, so I'd like to clarify how things stand at the moment.

Comment: You can’t, the solution out there open using private urls that don’t pass Apple review and some change often.