# Any way to open ACCESSIBILITY->Spoken Content -> Voices settings in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, settings

Based on this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152624/743663 you can open ACCESSIBILITY settings, but can I dig into more with URL settings like ACCESSIBILITY->Spoken content/ voices?

My app uses AI, so I want to give an option to users to change the AI voice on the screen easily at least.

I tried "App-prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY/SPOKEN_CONTENT", but it didn't work.

It navigates to accessibility but not to spoken content

```
guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: "App-prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY/SPOKEN_CONTENT") else {
                return
            }

            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                    print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                })
            }
```